# Logback hangs forever

Tags: java, deadlock, logback

I am writing a Java application to route a high number of concurrent messages. The application uses the Logback framework for logging and I am seeing a surprising behavior where the application hangs. In a stack trace, I can see that application threads are stuck in logging calls:

```
"New I/O client worker #1-1" #125 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0524017000 nid=0x29f3 waiting on condition [0x00007f052ecea000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00007f089c4a7e88> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
        at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.remainingCapacity(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:468)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase.isQueueBelowDiscardingThreshold(AsyncAppenderBase.java:152)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.AsyncAppenderBase.append(AsyncAppenderBase.java:144)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.doAppend(UnsynchronizedAppenderBase.java:84)
        at ch.qos.logback.core.spi.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:51)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.appendLoopOnAppenders(Logger.java:270)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callAppenders(Logger.java:257)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:421)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:579)
        at com.application.ClientListener$6.operationComplete(***.java:514)
        - locked <0x00007f089c372b60> (a com.application.ClientListener)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:381)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:372)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setSuccess(DefaultChannelFuture.java:316)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker$RegisterTask.run(NioWorker.java:776)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processRegisterTaskQueue(NioWorker.java:257)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:199)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00007f08a80fc118> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

It seems that the logging call is blocked trying to acquire an lock `<0x00007f089c4a7e88>`
inside a `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue` instance used in `AsyncAppenderBase`.

In the stack trace, I can see that the lock `<0x00007f089c4a7e88>` is held by another thread in a thread pool that is idle:

```
"dispatcher-3" #90 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f04d0004800 nid=0x29d2 waiting on condition [0x00007f0534ed3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00007f089cbbaae8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:809)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00007f089c4a7e88> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

It looks like the internal lock of the `ArrayBlockingQueue` was held by that thread and subsequently
not released.

What is going on here? A race condition in `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`? A bug in Logback?

I am using Java 8u40 and Logback 1.2.1.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Are you using Spring Boot or JBoss by any chance?

Comment: I get the same issue.  @glerup did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set [asyncAppender neverBlock](https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1424?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) option to true for this to work.

Comment: it won't work since this line of code occurs before consuming neverBlock